# How to return a grid of numbers from 1-D int array?

Tags: c#, arrays, datagrid, language-agnostic

At the moment, I have a 1D array of ints that are used to form a 9x9 grid of numbers (but could be any size).
I would like to input an index and return a 3x3 grid of numbers, effectively breaking the 9x9 grid up into 3x3 grids (Think Sudoku).

So far I have tried two nested loops, one that loops for the height of the grid, and inside that, one that loops for the width of the grid. But I'm having trouble making it work with anything other than the first 3x3 grid, or when the size changes from 9x9.

What I have so far:

```
int squareWidth = 3;
int squareHeight = 3;

int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = index; j < 3; j++)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(array[j]);
    }
   index+=9;
}
```

4x4 Grid example should return a 2x2 grid but in a 1D array.

Imagine the first 2x2 grid is 1,2,2,4. The numbers found at index 0,1,4,5.

The second 2x2 grid is 7,2,4,5. The numbers found at index 2,3,6,7.

```
var gameboard = new int[] { 
1, 2, 7, 2,
2, 4, 4, 5,
4, 2, 1, 3,
3, 1, 2, 2 };
```

`GetByGrid(2);`

Should return

```
7,2,4,5
```

Since I input 2 into `GetByGrid()` it should return the 2x2 grid

`GetByGrid(3);`

Should return

```
4,2,3,1
```

Further clarification on how the grid is broken up. This is a 4x4 playing board with four 2x2 grids. A 9x9 playing board would have 9 3x3 grids.

```
1,2 | 7,2
2,4 | 4,5
---------
4,2 | 1,3
3,1 | 2,2
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of how to get those answers?

Comment: How on earth does, `GetByGrid(3)` return `4,2,3,1`

Comment: Will all arrays be strictly square? you can get 4 grids from a 4x4 grid and 9 grids from a 9x9 grid but what do you do with a 5x5 grid? what's the criteria for breaking up a grid? GetByGrid(2) can also return `7,2` in your example if I decide to break your initial grid into 8 subgrids, not 4. would you like to pass another parameter specifying how a grid should be broken up?

Comment: The grid sizing is manually set in another function. But we can expect all grids to be square, and evenly broken up into grids of the same size. The full 1D array will always have enough numbers to form a 4x4 board, 9x9 board, 16x16 etc.

Comment: if you know the dimensions of the grid and you know the (row, column) coordinates of each element of the sub dimensional space you want, you should be able to use the formula (dimension) * row + column to figure out the position in the 1d array to pull a value from.  So for example above, 4,2,3,1 is in (row 2, column 0), (row 2, column 1), (row 3, column 0), (row 3, column 1).  The formula for getting it out of the 1d array is 4*row + column.  For row 3 column, column 1, this is 4*3 + 1 = 13  (remember the rows and columns are start at 0)

Comment: Just to clarify there are `n×n` subgrids each with `n×n` elements, for a total number of elements `n^4`? Like each subgrid being 5×5, and having 5 of them across the horizontal for a total of 625 elements? Or the `n=3` board having `n^4=9×9=81` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help

Heres how I solved it

Height, Width, the length of a row are all defined elsewhere

```
public void GridToSquare(squareIndex)
{
int rowNum = squareIndex / (maxNum / width) * height;
int colNum = squareIndex % (maxNum / width) * width;

       for (int row = rowNum; row < height + rowNum; row++)
       {
           for (int column = colNum; column < width + colNum; column++)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(theArray[maxNum * row + column]);
           }
       } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use OOP and create a game board class with an indexer for the grid elements and a method to return the sub-matrix. Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var game = new GameBoard(3);
        // Fill the board with sequencial number (the index).
        var index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < game.SubGridCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < game.SubGridCount; j++)
            {
                game[i, j] = index++;
            }
        }
        // game = 
        // +----------+----------+----------+
        // |  0  1  2 |  3  4  5 |  6  7  8 |
        // |  9 10 11 | 12 13 14 | 15 16 17 |
        // | 18 19 20 | 21 22 23 | 24 25 26 |
        // +----------+----------+----------+
        // | 27 28 29 | 30 31 32 | 33 34 35 |
        // | 36 37 38 | 39 40 41 | 42 43 44 |
        // | 45 46 47 | 48 49 50 | 51 52 53 |
        // +----------+----------+----------+
        // | 54 55 56 | 57 58 59 | 60 61 62 |
        // | 63 64 65 | 66 67 68 | 69 70 71 |
        // | 72 73 74 | 75 76 77 | 78 79 80 |
        // +----------+----------+----------+
        var data = game.ToArray();
        // [0,1,2,3,4,5...79,80]

        var A11 = game.GetSubArray(0, 0);
        // [0,1,2,9,10,11,18,19,20]
        var A12 = game.GetSubArray(0, 1);
        // [3,4,5,12,13,14,21,22,23]
        var A13 = game.GetSubArray(0, 2);
        // [6,7,8,15,16,17,24,25,25]
        var A32 = game.GetSubArray(2, 1);
        // [57,58,59,66,67,68,75,76,77]

        // In the A23 subgrid, get the (3,1) element
        var x2331 = game[1, 2, 2, 0];
        // 51
    }
}
```

with the `GameBoard` definition as

```
public class GameBoard 
{
    public GameBoard(int subGridSize)
    {
        this.SubGridSize = subGridSize;
        this.SubGridCount = subGridSize*subGridSize;
        this.Elements = new int[subGridSize*subGridSize*subGridSize*subGridSize];
    }
    public int SubGridSize { get; }
    public int SubGridCount { get; }
    int[] Elements { get; }

    public int this[int row, int col]
    {
        get => Elements[SubGridCount*row+col];
        set => Elements[SubGridCount*row+col] = value;
    }
    public int this[int grid_row, int grid_col, int row, int col]
    {
        get => Elements[SubGridCount*(grid_row*SubGridSize+row) + grid_col*SubGridSize + col];
        set => Elements[SubGridCount*(grid_row*SubGridSize+row) + grid_col*SubGridSize + col] = value;
    }

    // Make a copy of the elements
    public int[] ToArray() => Elements.Clone() as int[];

    public int[] GetSubArray(int grid_row, int grid_col)
    {
        var array = new int[SubGridCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < SubGridSize; i++)
        {
            var first_element = SubGridCount * (grid_row*SubGridSize+i) + grid_col* SubGridSize;
            for (int j = 0; j < SubGridSize; j++)
            {
                array[i*SubGridSize + j] = Elements[first_element +j];
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

---

**Future Work**

For more flexibility, you can add a `SubGrid` class that contains `n×n` elements so you can have more methods specific to the subgrids. For example:

```
        var S32 = game.GetSubGrid(2, 1);
        Debug.WriteLine(S32.ToString());
        // 57  58  59
        // 66  67  68
        // 75  76  77
```

using the definition

```
public class SubGrid 
{
    public SubGrid(int size)
    {
        this.Size = size;
        this.Elements = new int[size*size];
    }
    public SubGrid(int size, int[] elements)
    {
        this.Size = size;
        this.Elements  = elements;
    }
    public int Size { get; }
    public int[] Elements { get; }
    public int this[int row, int col]
    {
        get => Elements[Size*row+col];
        set => Elements[Size*row+col] = value;
    }
    public int[] ToArray() => Elements.Clone() as int[];

    public override string ToString()
    {
        const int col_size = 3;
        // print the grid
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            var row = Elements.Skip(i*Size).Take(Size);
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(" ", row.Select((x) => $"{x,-col_size}")));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```